# React: Can I return the result of previous render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following situation:

- In order to show a modal dialog, I need to first gather some information and store it in redux.
- The pattern library I need to use uses a wrapper portal component for animation support. This is always in the react tree.
- The modal, however is only in the react tree when I have `isOpen = true`
- The opening animation works fine, but since I render the modal conditionally, the closing animation breaks, since the modal is gone after close.

I am not sure if my idea to solve this is an acceptable method:

```
const RenderComponent = (props) => {
    const content = useRef(null);
    if (props.isOpen) {
        content.current = props.render();
    }
    return content.current;
};
```

This returns null if the modal has not been opened yet (opened means all data is available). This is okay, since the animation only starts when it gets opened.

Once it has been opened, it will render the content into a reference and return that. Storing it in a reference allows me to also return it when isOpen turns false, since it still needs to be rendered for the animation.

So my question is: Is it okay to return the result of a previous render or will this cause unpredictable behavior?

**Edit: A bit more detail:**

The (company-wide) pattern library has two components: `ModalPortal` and `Modal`

I use the above components like this (simplified code):

```
const node = (
    <ModalPortal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
        <RenderComponent
            isOpen={isOpen}
            render={() => (
                <Modal title={data.title} onClose={closeModal}>
                    Content
                </Modal>
            )}
        />
    </ModalPortal>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to go from a functional component to a class based one so that you can have more control over the states and what you want happening in each.

An option could be to keep in mind **three** states for the modal instead of just two: "open", "closing", "closed". Since I don't know about the rest of your code, I am going to write some very generic code here to help illustrate my suggestion. It would be best to share some more in your question, since it's easier to help out with more info.

```
export const ModalStates = {
     "OPEN" : 1,
     "CLOSING" : 2,
     "CLOSED" : 3
};

export default class ModalComponent {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        'modal_state' : ModalStates.CLOSED
    };
}

render () {
    if(this.state.modal_state != ModalStates.CLOSED)
        return <div class="moda">Your modal HTML here</div>;
}
```

}

This would of course need to be expanded. Here you would need the logic that changes the modal to **open** and to the other states. The idea is that when you want the modal closed the steps could be:

1. Change modal state to **closing**
2. Carry out animation
3. When animation is finished, modal state's should change to *closed* so that it doesn't render any more.

Hope this helps guide you.

Comment: That would require changes in the(company-wide) pattern-library. Not sure if that is possible, but I guess I can always ask. Still wondering if my initial approach is without issues (aside from the ugliness of it). Gimme a few minutes, I will expand on the original question to give you more insight.

Comment: The original post has now a bit more detail.